# Tensorflow function that returns an array of random integers different to a given int

Tags: python, random, tensorflow

I would like to implement a code in tensorflow, given two numbers a,b and a number "true", return an array of random integers, everyone different to the true.

In simple python using random.randint would be something like

```
def get_a_rand(a,b,true, S):
    for i in range(S.shape[0]):
        k = True
        while (k):
            r = (randint(a,b))
            if r!= true:                
                k = False
                S[i] = r
            else:
                k = True
    return S
```

Where S for example:

```
S = np.zeros((4))
```

How can i define something like that using Tensorflow? 
Using this function maybe tf.random_uniform([],a ,b, dtype=tf.int32) ??

Comment: Please, for the love of god, tell me that that's not actually how you would write this loop and that it's just a joke.

Comment: Sorry, maybe seems totally stupid, but this is not a joke. I'm trying to understand how tensorflow works, so i' m making simple problems. I' m very confused with the loops in tensorflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you only want to take one element out of the range, and are sampling uniformly, I would suggest first generating from a range one smaller ([a, b - 1] instead of [a, b]), then adding 1 for values greater than or equal to the value you're taking out of the range.

In TensorFlow:

```
import tensorflow.google as tf
range_start = 0
range_end = 10 # inclusive
avoid_value = 3
value_count = 50
with tf.Session():
  # First sample from [range_start, range_end); maxval is exclusive
  one_smaller_range = tf.random_uniform(dtype=tf.int32, minval=range_start, maxval=range_end, shape=[value_count])
  # Increment for values >= the removed element
  sampled_numbers = tf.select(one_smaller_range >= avoid_value, one_smaller_range + 1, one_smaller_range)
  print(sampled_numbers.eval())
```